# (Django/Python/Javascript) Accessing a list of tuples in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django, list

In my views.py file, I am able to return two lists of tuples that contain a book title as the first element, and the book type as a second element. I am able to access these in html interchangably by creating for loops like "for each in booklist_latin" then use curly braces for the expressions `{{ each.0 }}` or `{{ each.1 }}` so yes, now I got my goal there.

But there's some filtering options that I need to take place based on the type of each book. So I need to be able to access the second element of each tuple within my lists of tuples, perhaps put it through a conditional of some sort. I do not know the syntax for doing that. I'm still learning Javascript and I still have a ways to go, let alone the fact I'm learning Django.

It's pretty efficient to be able to write `{{ each.0 }}` and get the first element the tuples I made in my views.py file. But how can I do that in Javascript? Will I have to jsonify anything? And if so could you provide an explanation or useful documentation on what that does in this context (I've been reading documentation, but seeing it in context would be helpful at this point).

I'm imaginging in pseudo code conditionals that I could make. For example `if( {{ each.1 }} == "textbook") { do some things...}`. If there's syntax that allows me to do something like that in Javascript, it'd be really helpful.

Here's the python code in views.py just in case it helps to see it.

```
def IndexView(request):
    sorted_latin_books=sorted(BookTitles.objects.all(),key=lambda book: (book.book_type,book.title_of_book))
    booklist_latin= [(book.title_of_book, book.book_type)
            for book in sorted_latin_books]
    print booklist_latin
    sorted_greek_books=sorted(BookTitlesGreek.objects.all(),key=lambda book: (book.book_type,book.title_of_book))
    booklist_greek= [(book.title_of_book, book.book_type)
            for book in sorted_greek_books]
    print booklist_greek
    return render(request, 'index.html',
            {"booklist_latin":booklist_latin,"booklist_greek":booklist_greek})
```

Comment: Can you post the template you're using?

Comment: You can also make filtering through django templating.  In general, the existing filtering options suit the most common cases you can face.  That way you don't have to deal with javascript.
Take a look at [Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/)